# I am using Excel to create a golf handicap

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have set up a golf handicap that is based off a golfer's index and the using this formula, index*slope/113 to get my final number which is a whole number.  I have set my cell format so there are no decimals.  However, when I try to copy the handicap result whole number to a tournament program uses decimals.  If I just type a number into the cell without a formula it transfers correctly.  Is there a way to hide the formula that produces the result I want and transfer as a whole number?  Any advice is appreciated.

Okay: Exact problem is that when I import my Excel spreadsheet into my totally separate golf tournament programs's database to update their handicap it converts my Excel formula to multiple decimals.  If I have an index of 3.6 and my formula rounds that to 4and I have my cell formatted so there are no decimals, when I import it changes the cell to a bunch of decimals like 3.6345789.  If I just type in the number 4 in the cell it comes over perfectly so I figure it has to have something to do where during the importing process the tournament software sees the formal in the cell instead of the final rounded number of 4.

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what your problem is. If you could edit the post to make it more clear we may be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try `=ROUND(index*slope/133,0)` which will round the result to 0 decimal places.